# Website/Facebook Interface Requirements for Minimal Information Retrieval

Tags: php, facebook, joomla

I am working on a website which will allow registered users to link with their Facebook account and periodically, the site will poll their information and post back to their Facebook page.

The site is Joomla based, so using the PHP API seemed most sensible, but I'm not sure.
I've looked at the Facebook documentation and it seems confusing. Do I need to write an app and get it approved, or is there a simpler way?

If I need to write an app, is there anyway to develop and debug the app before getting approval and only turn off sandbox mode after approval has been achieved?

What would be the simplest way to implement this so I can retrieve some Facebook info and make posts to Facebook pages at later dates?

In future, I may wish to allow users who are logged into Facebook to automatically login to my site, but for now, I do not want this.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register an application. Being that this is not an application hosted on facebook, there really isn't much of an approval process.

PHP SDK would be required for what you want to do.

In order to post to facebook or get facebook account information, the user would need to authorize your application and provide permission for what you want to do.

Keep in mind that although a user can grant your application a key via which you can do things on their behalf on facebook, this key will eventually expire if the user does not return to your application.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the Facebook API that was done for summer of code.  It is currently in the platform tracker and you also need the OAuth1 API that she did.  If if you use that you'll  have a good start on what you need.